# Dynamically Created Input Field's data not being posted

Tags: php, jquery

This is the Jquery Code I have used for creating two new Input Fields every time User clicks Add more Button

```
  var i=1;
                    $('#addMoreHighlights').on('click',function(event){
                        //prevent default action
                        event.preventDefault();
                        var clone = '<div data-count="'+i+'" ><br/><hr/><div class="form-group" ><label>Trip-Highlight Title:</label><input type="text" value="" name="trip_highlightTitle[]" class="form-control clearHiglights" id="" placeholder="Enter Trip Highlight\'s Title"></div><div class="form-group"><label>Trip-Highlight Image</label><div class="input-group"><input class="form-control clearHiglights" placeholder="Upload Image For The Highlight" name="trip_highlightImage[]" value="" type="text" id="trip_highlightImage"><span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #3C8DBC"> <a style="cursor: pointer;"  onclick="BrowseServer("trip_highlightImage");" ><span style="color: #FFF;">Select Image</span></a></span></div></div><button style="float: right; margin: 5px;" data-removeCount="'+i+'"class="removeMoreHighlights btn">Remove</button></div>';

                        $('#tripHighlights').append(clone);
                        i++;
                    });
```

This newly created element gets attached to the already existing form elements.This is my already existing input fields (html)

```
<div id="tripHighlights">

                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <label>Trip-Highlight Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="trip_highlightTitle[]" class="form-control clearHiglights" id="" placeholder="Enter Trip Highlight's Title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Trip-Highlight Image</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control clearHiglights" placeholder="Upload Image For The Highlight" name="trip_highlightImage[]" value="" type="text" id="trip_highlightImage">
                                <span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #3C8DBC">
                                    <a style="cursor: pointer;"  onclick="BrowseServer('trip_highlightImage');" >
                                        <span style="color: #FFF;">Select Image</span>
                                    </a>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <button id="addMoreHighlights" class="btn">Add-More</button>
```

All of this exists within the  tag But still during post I only get the input from fields that are initially generated in the DOM and not from the ones that is generated using jquery

This is my post result:

```
'trip_highlightTitle' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'title 1' (length=7)
  'trip_highlightImage' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image1' (length=6)
```

The actual result I expect is:

```
'trip_highlightTitle' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'title 1' (length=7)
      1 => string 'title 2'  (length=7)
  'trip_highlightImage' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'image1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'image2'  (length=6)
```

Comment: Where did you started & closed the form?

Comment: can you pass the index in the name attribute of each field and try again?

Comment: the form starts at the beginning of the page and ends at the end of the page @sgt

Comment: can you share the POST request code?

Comment: doesnot work it's still the same@Kalish

Comment: try to give dynamic id for the input in jquery code

Comment: post request do you mean the form's action and method if so then: <form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/page/save') }}" data-ng-app=""> I am using laravel so my action is bit different @Kalish

Comment: is id going make any differnce because the post data is going to be based on the name attribute or is there something related with id. It works fine if I don't generate input fields dynamically using jquery @AyyanarG

Comment: It seems that you use angularjs and your form submit only with fields are initialized at first. So I suggest you to learn how to add dynamically fields for angular form and how it properly process.

Comment: i just added form tag and action for your code got this in post-->array(2) { ["trip_highlightTitle"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "title" [1]=> string(4) "title1" } ["trip_highlightImage"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(7) "titleimg" [1]=> string(9) "title1-img" } }

Comment: i have used angularjs only  for simple data-binding and nothing else everything else is only jquery and php [laravel] and also if i remove all my angular code it still is not sending data as i expected. my problem is only with the dynamically generated input fields as data from them are not being posted while data from the input field that is not generated dynamiclly is being posted@Panoptik

Comment: so do you think i have problem with my form tag starting and closing@AyyanarG

Comment: So, can you share how are you submit your form. Suppose you save jquery form object into variable initially and its submit its copy after addition new fields. But form copy keep old fields and new items doesn't get into submit data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I used your code to create an example, and I can see the dynamically added fields are also part of the form submission. see if this helps!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i=1;
                    $('#addMoreHighlights').on('click',function(event){
                        //prevent default action
                        event.preventDefault();
                         var clone = '<div data-count="'+i+'" ><br/><hr/><div class="form-group" ><label>Trip-Highlight Title:</label><input type="text" value="" name="trip_highlightTitle[]" class="form-control clearHiglights" id="" placeholder="Enter Trip Highlight\'s Title"></div><div class="form-group"><label>Trip-Highlight Image</label><div class="input-group"><input class="form-control clearHiglights" placeholder="Upload Image For The Highlight" name="trip_highlightImage[]" value="" type="text" id="trip_highlightImage"><span class="input-group-addon" style="background: #3C8DBC"> <a style="cursor: pointer;"  onclick="BrowseServer("trip_highlightImage");" ><span style="color: #FFF;">Select Image</span></a></span></div></div><button style="float: right; margin: 5px;" data-removeCount="'+i+'"class="removeMoreHighlights btn">Remove</button></div>';

                        $('#tripHighlights').append(clone);
                        i++;
                    });
     $( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="test" id="test" action="test" method="post">
   <div id="tripHighlights">

                        <div class="form-group" >
                            <label>Trip-Highlight Title:</label>
                            <input type="text" value="" name="trip_highlightTitle[]" class="form-control clearHiglights" id="test1" placeholder="Enter Trip Highlight's Title">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Trip-Highlight Image</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control clearHiglights" placeholder="Upload Image For The Highlight" name="trip_highlightImage[]" value="" type="text" id="test2">
                               
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <button id="addMoreHighlights" class="btn">Add-More</button> 
     
      <button type="submit" class="boton" > Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" class="boton" style="float:right;"> Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've stumbled on is that you're using the same id attribute over and over in your clone HTML. I have corrected this here by adding your i-counter to the element's id attribute and it seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/8ho414nn/4

```
var clone = '<div data-count="' + i + '" ><br/><hr/>'
          + '<div class="form-group" ><label>'
          ...
          + 'type="text" id="trip_highlightImage' + i + '">'
          ...
          + '"class="removeMoreHighlights btn">'
          + 'Remove</button></div>';
```